# How to return settings from an object

Tags: coffeescript

i have done something like this:

```
myProject =

  settings:
    duration: 500
    value: 'aValue'

  aFunction: ->
    myElement.fadeOut myProject.settings.duration
```

This is just a sample but my project is like that. A lot of times i have to reference to the settings to get a certain value, and i always have to write `myProject.settings.value`, and it doesn´t look good.

My question is, can I call a function that returns the wanted value? Something like this:

```
aFunction: ->
  myElement.fadeOut getSetting(duration)
```

I tried with

```
getSetting: (param) ->
  myProject.settings.param
```

but failed? Why is that? 
Thank you!

Comment: failed how? do you get an error?

Comment: i always get `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an object property by a variable, you can do:

```
object[key]
```

In coffeescript, the last line should be the return value, in your example:
Please note the @ (= this).

```
myProject =

  settings:
    duration: 500
    value: 'aValue'

  fadeOut: ($element) ->
    $element.fadeOut @getSetting('duration')

  getSetting: (key) ->
    @settings[key]

myProject.fadeOut($myElement)
```

The javascript :

```
var myProject;

myProject = {
  settings: {
    duration: 500,
    value: 'aValue'
  },
  fadeOut: function($element) {
    return $element.fadeOut(this.getSetting('duration'));
  },
  getSetting: function(key) {
    return this.settings[key];
  }
};

myProject.fadeOut($myElement);
```

Comment: Yes, this works! But i want to pass the wanted param like `myElement.fadeOut(aFunction(duration))` - I have around 10 to 15 params stored. My current solution works but looks like `myElement.fadeOut(myProject.settings.duration)`

Comment: Hmm, when I think about it - if there is no better solution, @settings makes my code a little nicer!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you really wanted, please see my edit (the Fiddle has been edited). The important part is @settings[key] and not @settings.key.