# How to return n-values from an object with coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

yesterday @SuperSkunk soved this little problem for me: [How to return settings from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797014/how-to-return-settings-from-an-object)

I had this setup to retrieve values from stored settings:

```
myProject =

 settings:
  value1: one
  value2: two
  value3: three

 getSetting: (key) ->
  @settings[key]
```

So when i call `getSetting('value1')` i get `one`.

How can I change the code to pass n-Arguments to get n-Values? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a splat and list comprehensions:

```
getSetting: (keys...) ->
   (@settings[key] for key in keys)
```

Now if you call `getSettings 'value1', 'value2'` the result is the array `['one', 'two']`.

To "return as they are" means probably simply to destructure on receiving the values

so taking the above example on the caller side you do

```
[value1, value2] = getSettings "value1", "value2"
```

Comment: Thank you! I  was experimenting with splats but couldn´t get it work. I´m curious - is there a chance to return the values "as they are" and not as array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "as they are"? If you want to return a new hash with just these keys set you can use something like getSetting: (keys...) ->
   result = {};
   result[key] = @settings[key] for key in keys;
   result

Comment: When i use the "single argument call" (like in my question) i get strings and numbers - like they are stored. When i get an array or hash-table my follow-up functions won´t work, as they require strings or numbers. Your code works fine - I guess there is no easy way to pick each element out of the array or hashtable and return them... So that the outcome would be `left, 250, red` for example instead of `[left, 250, red]` - But maybe thats a new question

Comment: I was playing a little bit and came up with this line, after your suggested code: `console.log "#{value}" for key, value of result` -> a big leap forward! so my last question would be: **how to return the values in one line, seperated with comma?**

Answer (score -1):

To use the below, please include underscore.js  (http://underscorejs.org) or the coffee script variant (http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/underscore.html)

`getSettings: (keys) ->
  _.map(_.flatten([keys]), (key) -> @settings(key))`

The above should work with either an array passed in or a single value as above..

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but I want to keep the project as it is - as it is enough of a struggle :)